# Why i'm getting ' The method '[]' was called on null ' in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So i have a **notification screen** with a **MediaPreview**(to show the image next to it's notification).
and when (**on Tap**) on media preview i want to **redirect** to another page to show the image, for some reason it's giving me **The method[] was called on null**

here is my code to showing Post when i tap on the image

```
    showPost(context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PostScreen(
          postId: postId,
          userId: userId,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and here is the code for PostScreen :

```
class PostScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userId;
  final String postId;

  PostScreen({this.postId, this.userId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: postsRef
          .document(userId)
          .collection('userPosts')
          .document(postId)
          .get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }
        Post post = Post.fromDocument(snapshot.data);
        return Center(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: header(context, appTitle: post.description),
            body: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: post,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `Post.fromDocument` code too?

Comment: Try to debug your code and detect on which line its fall

Comment: @Nolence : factory Post.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return Post(
      postId: doc['postId'],
      ownerId: doc['ownerId'],
      username: doc['username'],
      location: doc['location'],
      description: doc['description'],
      mediaUrl: doc['mediaUrl'],
      likes: doc['likes'],
    );
  }

Comment: @dubace Debug Console show's : User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was
    PostScreen.

Comment: i understand, but i can't see where do you initialize `posRef` library, so it could happend in your `future` attribute or in your builder function, you can detect it with breakpoints

Comment: @dubace i Created postsRef in home : { final postsRef = Firestore.instance.collection('posts'); }

Comment: i don't see whats home is. Add more code into your example

Comment: @dubace home is where i create a user and use GoogleSignIn and creating Firestore instances for my collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a **solution** after using a **debugger and breakpoint** in `Post post = Post.fromDocument(snapshot.data);` i found that the **postId** was not found in the a userId **posts Collection** (let's call it user A), so user **A** have no post with this **postId** but user **B** **had the post** i've been looking for. So, i changed my showPost function from :

`showPost(context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PostScreen(
          postId: postId,
          userId: userId,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }`

to

`showPost(context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PostScreen(
          postId: postId,
          userId: currentUser?.id,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }`

that way when i click on another *user* post (i get that **userId** to get his **posts collection**) and when i click on **my post** (i get **my userId** to get **my** posts Collection).

Hope this will help.